# How do I add NULL column to a new table based on a existing delta table while using SQL databricks?

Tags: azure-sql-database, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake, databricks-sql

I tried to make a new table from a delta table and adding a new NULL column while using using SQL databricks. Databricks is not able to make a NULL column, if i fill the newly made column it works fine. How do I add NULL column to a new table based on a existing delta table?

[Does not work when NULL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fthLU.png)

When I fill the column it works.

[It Works when filled with 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRysh.png)

It returns the following error:

```html
com.databricks.backend.common.rpc.DatabricksExceptions$SQLExecutionException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: Binding attribute, tree: Parent_name#23885
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BindReferences$$anonfun$bindReference$1.applyOrElse(BoundAttribute.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BindReferences$$anonfun$bindReference$1.applyOrElse(BoundAttribute.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:484)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:484)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:428)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BindReferences$.bindReference(BoundAttribute.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BindReferences$.$anonfun$bindReferences$1(BoundAttribute.scala:96)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:238)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:238)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:231)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BindReferences$.bindReferences(BoundAttribute.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.doConsume(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.consume(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.consume$(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ColumnarToRowExec.consume(Columnar.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ColumnarToRowExec.doProduce(Columnar.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.$anonfun$produce$1(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.produce$(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ColumnarToRowExec.produce(Columnar.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.doProduce(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.$anonfun$produce$1(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport.produce$(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.produce(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doCodeGen(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:657)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:720)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:209)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$.collect(Collector.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$.collect(Collector.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.InternalRowFormat$.collect(cachedSparkResults.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.InternalRowFormat$.collect(cachedSparkResults.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.$anonfun$getOrComputeResultInternal$1(ResultCacheManager.scala:512)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.getOrComputeResultInternal(ResultCacheManager.scala:511)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.getOrComputeResult(ResultCacheManager.scala:399)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollectResult(limit.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectResult(Dataset.scala:3031)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$collectResult$1(Dataset.scala:3022)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3815)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$5(SQLExecution.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:269)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:852)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3813)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectResult(Dataset.scala:3021)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.OutputAggregator$.withOutputAggregation0(OutputAggregator.scala:263)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.OutputAggregator$.withOutputAggregation(OutputAggregator.scala:97)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.executeSql(SQLDriverLocal.scala:115)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.repl(SQLDriverLocal.scala:144)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.$anonfun$execute$13(DriverLocal.scala:542)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(UsageLogging.scala:240)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:235)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:232)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:51)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:279)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:271)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:51)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:519)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$1(DriverWrapper.scala:689)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:681)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.getCommandOutputAndError(DriverWrapper.scala:522)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:634)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:427)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:370)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:221)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't find Parent_name#23885 in [Source_id#23886,Rol_code#23887]
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BindReferences$$anonfun$bindReference$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(BoundAttribute.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:52)
    ... 85 more

    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.executeSql(SQLDriverLocal.scala:129)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.repl(SQLDriverLocal.scala:144)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.$anonfun$execute$13(DriverLocal.scala:542)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(UsageLogging.scala:240)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:235)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:232)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:51)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:279)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:271)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:51)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:519)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$1(DriverWrapper.scala:689)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:681)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.getCommandOutputAndError(DriverWrapper.scala:522)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:634)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:427)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:370)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:221)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have a column with `null` value without specification of the type for this column, so you need to select a specific type for it, and cast `null` to that type.

Change the code from `select null as parent_name, ....` to the `select cast(null as string) as parent_name, ....` (change the type if necessary)